# Changes in Opencart stylesheet dont working

Tags: css, opencart, frontend

I'm doing some changes in opencart's default stylesheet, but they don't appear in the opencart. I'm trying to let the menu bar green:

```
#menu {
    background-color: Green;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, Green, ForestGreen);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: Gray;
    min-height: 40px;
}
```

I saved the file and reloaded the page, but any I didn't see any diference.

Comment: Is OpenCart using the default theme? Do some troubleshooting - do a "view source".  Which stylesheet is loading? Click through (in view source) and view the styles - are your changes there? Open your browser console, inspect - what styles are applied?

Comment: Yes is the default theme and it has the original colors code in the menu part

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: maybe, it is browser cache issue. please remove your browser cache & then check it.

Answer (score 0):

That is Browser Cache issue , if you are using Google Chrome

Press F12 on the far right side you will see 3 dots click them and select **"Settings"** Scroll down to  **"Network"** and check the **Disable Cache (While DevTools is open)** now every time you make a change in your website
Open the console (F12) and than press F5 (Or refresh the page) and you will get your site loaded without any browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Whan you reload the page, do this with **Ctrl + f5**. Its combination updates your cache browser. Try it